# Pandas: Create new column that displays the total number of rows of each group of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column called **TotalCountByCycle** that displays the total number of rows in each group of the **Cycle** column and also appears in every row belonging to that **Cycle** group.

Here is an example of a simplified table:

```
raw_data = {'Reagent': ['H20', 'MWS', 'H20_1', 'H20', 'MWS', 'H20_1', 'H20_2', 'H20_3'], 
        'Cycle': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
        'Day': ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Reagent', 'Cycle', 'Day'])
df
```

I am trying to achieve the column on the right in the image below:

[image: Desired Table]

I tried the code below, but got the error, ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.

`df['new_col'] = df.groupby('Cycle').transform('count')`

Solved! Refer to comments below.

Comment: How do `1` and `3` for `H20` become `3` and `5` in the output table? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] including a more specific problem description and code for what you've tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

groupby then transform by the count and assign to new column

```
df['TotalCountByCycle'] = df.groupby('Cycle')['Reagent'].transform('count')
```

Comment: panda's transform is really underused!

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my example table, but it failed for my original because I have a a total of 15 columns. I'll edit my question. I get the message ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 15, placement implies 1.

Comment: @MP Since you have more than two columns you need to pick a column to count: `df['TotalCountByCycle'] = df.groupby('Cycle')['Reagent'].transform('count')`